# Android multiple (tablet + phone) layous with fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I've read the official documentation with regards to designing apps for both phone and tablet here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

However, I'm unable to relate this to my use-case. My app is made of 4 main screens, all accessed using a view-pager which only works on fragments and as such, I have 4 top level fragments embedded inside my main FragmentActivity which are arranged in a tab layout structure with a view pager.

Question is: would it be possible to somehow achieve the different design for phone/tablet using fragments instead of activities? Based on the link above, if I was using fragments instead of activities for my top level items, it would be simple since I would simply instantiate a different layout with the same fragments but from what I understand, up until very recently, fragments were not able to include other fragments in them and since I would like my app to be accessible for older phones (I'm targeting SKD v14), I don't think I'm able to achieve this using different fragment layouts and composite fragments.

Ideally, I would love to be able to have the same code base and use the same fragments for both tablets and phones, albeit define separate layouts for each device, but I'm not sure on how to go about it.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: `achieve the different design for phone/tablet using fragments instead of activities` are you going to launch an app without any activity at the top but only the fragment ??

Comment: No I have one top level activity whose layout is a view pager. Inside the activity, I'm creating 4 main fragments which can be accessed via swiping the screen. Each of these fragments can (and indeed does) spawn other activities which is ok since for those use-cases I know how to support multiple layout but for my main screen, I'm stuck.

Comment: did you create different layout in different resolution folder?
`res/layout/my_layout.xml`
`res/layout-large/my_layout.xml`

Comment: I did but the issue is still the same. The main activity layout will still be a view pager. I'll add some concept drawings later today so that it's easier to understand the question. Cheers.

Comment: please post the layout.xml file

Answer (score 0):

you can display two fragments simultaneously on tablet whereas on phone you can show one fragment at a time-that is the main flexibility fragments provide.refer gmail app screenshots for phone and tablet and you will get better idea about what I am talking about-https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gm.

If you dont have similar UI flow as gmail(click on UI element in one fragment to open other fragment to show details) I dont think using fragments will provide much benefits.

Comment: Thanks. I'll add some concept drawings when I get home to explain the issue. my layout is not exactly like the Gmail layout but it's not too dissimilar. Imagine 4 "mail" views next to each other than can be swiped and each contain items that can be expanded. Much easier to explain with drawings which I will provide later today.